# Prove that if q is a quadratic residue in mod p where p is a prime of form 4m+1 then -q is also a quadratic residue in mod p?

Tags: number-theory

I was just playing with numbers and observed that if q is a quadratic residue in mod p where( p is a prime number of form 4k+1 ) then -q is also a quadratic residue in mod p .Can some one please prove or disprove  this fact.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Use the first complementary law of quadratic reciprocity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true.  If $\ a\ $ is a primitive element of $\ \mathbb{Z}_p\ $ then $\ a^{p-1}\equiv a^{4m}\equiv1 \pmod{p}\ $, but $\ a^{2m}\not\equiv 1\pmod{p}\ $, so $\ a^{2m} \equiv \left(a^m\right)^2\pmod{p}\ $ has to be $\ -1\pmod{p}\ $. Thus $\ -1\ $ is a quadratic residue mod $p$, and so $\ -q\ $ must also be one whenever $\ q\ $ is.

Comment: please explain why have you written a^2m is not congruent to 1 mod p

Comment: By definition, a [primitive root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n)  $\ a\pmod{p}\ $ (which must exist, because $\ p\ $ is prime) has multiplicative order $\ p−1\ $, which means that $\ a^n\not\equiv1\pmod{p}\ $ for any $\ n<p\ $, and, in particular, that $\ a^{2m}=a^\frac{p-1}{2}\not\equiv1\pmod{p}\ $.